# Определение типов предложений

Tags: синтаксис

1. *Следователь из окружной прокуратуры дал камердинеру четверть часа вещички собрать - да под присмотром городового, **чтоб не дай Бог не упер чего хозяйского**.* (целевое?)
2. *Я могу говорить всё **что думаю***. (относительное придаточное?)
3. *Я вам такое расскажу, **что вы убедитесь***… (следствия?)
4. *У нее было такое декольте, **что он покраснел***. (следствия?)
5. *Таланты, заложенные в женскую натуру, часто бывают такого свойства, **что мораль современного общества не готова их должным образом воспринимать***. (следствия?)
6. ***Разве что если по-французски объясняетесь***… (условия?)
7. *Ты не сердись, **что я тебя давно не навещала***. (изъяснительное)
8. ***Сбежал*** - значит замешан. (условия?)

А в следующих я не уверена:

9. *Награда такая, **что на двоих не поделишь***. (следствия или относительное?)
10. *Это она любит, коллекцию собирать, **и чтоб непременно экспонаты обновлялись***. (целевое или изъявительное (=*любит, чтобы экспонаты обновлялись*)?)

Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Aer, боюсь, что ваша правка не соответствует ситуации. **"Бог" с  заглавной** - это авторское право, хотя согласен, здесь я бы тоже написал со строчной, но если автор видит здесь реального Бога, а не некий условный объект, то и пишет с заглавной. Но самое главное: **не упер** - верно. Не усиление здесь, отрицание. Не должно быть тут "ни упер" ни по каким правилам. "чтобы не упер" - семантика придаточного, "не дай Бог" - усилительное по смыслу, по функции близкое к вводному.

Comment: Кстати, точно не будет ошибкой обособить его. А вот без обособления - что-то сомневаюсь .http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_467

Comment: я сохранила пунктуацию оригинала во всех примерах...

Comment: Вы правильно сделали. Но ведь и на Акунина бывает проруха. Хотя если уж цитировать, то не только пунктуацию, а вообще все дословно. Спросил про обособление на другом форуме. http://gramophone.myqip.ru/?1-0-0-00000008-000-0-0-1469602462

Comment: @Behemothus: Вы правы, но я сильно боюсь, что когда будут проверять мою работу, может выидут на то, что я искала помощь на этом саите... у нас с плагиатом очень строго... поэтому сокращаю примеры или формулирую немного по другому

Comment: А, черт.... Не подумал. Но должен сказать, что Ваши тайны - секрет Полишинеля. Гугл все равно легко находит ваши вопросы тут. Так что Вам лучше ответы формулировать так, чтобы связь с тутошними была неочевидна. А в таком случае это уже не плагиат, а нормальное обсуждение и дополнительные источники. Неужели ваши кураторы и это пресекают?

Comment: @behemothus боюсь, я с вами не согласен, однако чья музыка, того и танцы. В русской традиционной (назовем ее так) орфографии вне зависимости от веры в сверхъестественное существо в междометных выражениях типа *слава богу* *Бог* пишется со строчной буквы.

Comment: @Aer Так это Вы Акунину объясните про музыку. А мне - правило, на основании которого, "Слава Богу" всегда пишется по вашему разумению **в церковно-синодальной (назовем так(с)) орфографии**. И вообще где там Бог пишется со строчной?! Авторское право же не в том, чтобы не соблюдать орфографию, а в том, чтобы при выборе допустимых вариантов руководствоваться своим пониманием контекста и ситуации.

Comment: Вопрос о грамматической роли "слава Богу" оставляем открытым. Хотя не думаю, что у героя Акунина здесь междометие.

Comment: @behemothus пожалуйста, расставляйте запятые, трудно понять, что у вас написано. Музыка ваша, на мой взгляд (я не знаю, как работает система StackExchange, но если вы оставили первый комментарий, то, очевидно, не просто так). Акунину ничего объяснять не собираюсь, потому что  отношусь к его творчеству с неприязнью. Откуда тут взялась церковно-синодальная орфография (что это?) god only knows. Мы с вами не Библию редактируем. Откройте академические правила русской орфографии и смотрите параграф 181 примечание 3.

Comment: @aer Насчет запятых. У меня в комментариях одна ошибка случайная. Лишняя запятая после "которого", извините, править комментарии уже нельзя. Да, я оставил первый комментарий, но он никак не был связан с тем что вы понимаете "под заказывать музыку". И это объяснил

Comment: @behemothus дело в том, что, когда я готовил ответ, вы еще не отредактировали свой комментарий про церковно-синодальную орфографию. Я не упрекаю вас в пунктуационных ошибках. В данном случае под "заказыванием музыки" имеется в виду право утверждения предложенных изменений.

Comment: Мы с Вами ничего не редактируем. И ещё мы не посылаем друг друга неизвестно куда искать того, чего там нету. Где в Вашем академическом справочнике написано, что у героя Акунина это междометие в котором имел в виду академический бог, который со строчной пишется? И что его внутренняя орфография вообще подчиняется справочникам, изданным столетием позже? Вообще меня больше интересует отсутствие обособления у Акунина. Вот это действительно ничем не объяснимо.

Comment: *дело в том, что, когда я готовил ответ, вы еще не отредактировали свой комментарий* - комментарии редактируются не позже, чем через 5 мин. Что я там успел такого отредактировать-то, что поменялся смысл?

Comment: Ладно, давайте в чат, а то движок уже ругается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43075/discussion-between-behemothus-and-aer).

Comment: @Behemothus: да, очень очень строго... *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Придаточное **цели** (относится к присоединительной конструкции, обособленной тире).

2) **Местоименно-определительное** (местоименная связь: местоимение ВСЁ в роли указательного и опорного слова , ЧТО - союзное слово).

3,4,5) Переходный тип придаточных с местоименно-союзной связью,  двойное значение определительных придаточных (**определение + следствие**, указательное местоимение ТАКОЙ и союз ЧТО со значением следствия).

6) **Условие**, осложненный союз РАЗВЕ ЧТО ЕСЛИ (= ЕСЛИ ТОЛЬКО).

7) **Изъяснительное**, опорный глагол "сердиться" со значением эмоционального состояния.

8) **Сбежал - значит, замешан**. В предложениях такой структуры чаще ставится тире, сравнить:

"Знаете, как мы отличаем, чьи окопы нащупали? Пола нет ― значит, наши". "То есть он обязан теперь жить по закону велосипеда: остановился ― значит, упал".  Это **БСП** (нет союза, значение  **обоснования)**, но при наличии союза **СПП** с придаточным **условия**:  Раз вы читаете это мое письмецо, значит, я вас уже покинул.

9) Награда такая, что (=какую) на двоих не поделишь. Придаточное **местоименно-определительное** (скзуемостного типа), указательное слово ТАКОЙ, союзное слово (**не союз!**) ЧТО.

10) **Это** она любит, коллекцию собирать, **и чтоб** непременно экспонаты обновлялись. Придаточное **изъяснительное**, причем оно  находится в **однородных отношениях** с дополнением "это".

Comment: Большое спасибо, Sibylla! так рада сеичас! оказалось я думала почти в правильном направлении : ) 
у меня вопрос по поводу терминологии: 
"местоименно-определительные предлож." - это какая-то субкатегория "относительных предложен." или у меня устаревшие термины?

Comment: Знаете, Anonym, подсчитано, что у лингвистов применяются 4  классификции СПП:  (1) по аналогии с членами предложения (подлежащные и т.д.), (2) по аналогии с частями речи (субстантивные, адъективные и т.д.), (3) формальная классификация по средствам связи (союз или союзное слово), (4) структурно-семантическая по целому комплексу признаков. Да еще есть упрощенная  "школьная" классификация. Вообще существуют два больших класса  СПП: нерасчлененные (ПРИСЛОВНЫЕ) с основной МЕСТОИМЕННОЙ связью и расчлененные с союзной связью (ПРИСОСТАВНЫЕ, придаточные относят к главному предложению).

Comment: Ваши "относительные" предложения - это первый тип. Среди них можно выделить определительные (указ. мест.ТОТ, ТАКОЙ + опорное сущ.) и местоименно-определительные,  без опорного существительного. Это - по упрощенной школьной классификции. Как видите, часто приходится называть несколько признаков при определении структуры предложения.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в 1) используется сослагательное наклонение в придаточном цели? (чтоб не упер)

Comment: В придаточных цели модальность желательности выражается двумя способами: а)сослагательным наклонением глагола; б) инфинитивом, сравнить:  мы довезли Петю, чтобы он не опоздал на поезд; мы поехали на вокзал, чтобы встретить Петю. Модальность в первом случае выражается  союзом ЧТОБЫ и формой глагол на -Л, частица БЫ (показатель модальности) входит в союз.